# while returing values in single line

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax and returning values by the following method

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM symptom WHERE symptom LIKE '%$key%'")or die('couldnt select');
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))!=false){

    echo $row['disease'];

}
```

but the result received in ajax function shows the result like

```
streppneumonia
```

instead of

```
strep
pneumonia
```

What am i doing wrong?I just can't figure out the problem here.

Comment: `!= false` doesn't really do much in a language like PHP. You might want to try `!== false`.

Comment: @waleed !==false didn't work either... i did the same thing elsewhere and its working like a charm there but its not working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using ajax and returning multiple values, send it in the [json](http://www.json.org/) format. You cannot distinguish the multiple values although you can break with break tag on the client side:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM symptom WHERE symptom LIKE '%$key%'")or die('couldnt select');
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))!=false){

    $diseases[] =  $row['disease'];

} 

echo json_encode($diseases);

?>
```

Later, decode by js on the client side

Comment: how to decode this?i'm getting result as ["strep","pneumonia"] now and on doing jQuery.parseJSON(result) in javascript still gives ["strep","pneumonia"].How do you decode it correctly?

Comment: var arr =  jQuery.parseJSON(result) ; ["strep","pneumonia"] states nothing but an array. so, arr[0] => will give u "strep",arr[1] => ...

Answer (score 3):

Quick fix: `echo $row['disease'].'<br />';`

Although really your your web service should return data in a better format like JSON, and from there you should use javascript to break the data up.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo $row['disease'].'<br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM symptom WHERE symptom LIKE '%$key%'")or die('couldnt select');
$str = '';
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))!=false){

    $str .= $row['disease']. "<br>";

} 

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))){

    echo $row['disease'].'<br>';

}
```

**Note**

`mysql_*` function are deprecated please use `PDO` or `MySQLi`